# Substrate BoundedVec Error Cannot Borrow as mutable

Tags: frame, boundedvec

I have substrate pallet structure as follows

```rust
#[derive(
    Encode, Decode, CloneNoBound, PartialEqNoBound, Eq, RuntimeDebugNoBound, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen,
)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(MetadataSize))]
#[codec(mel_bound(AccountId: MaxEncodedLen, BlockNumber: MaxEncodedLen))]
pub struct DataLog<AccountId, BlockNumber, MetadataSize>
where
    AccountId: Clone + PartialEq + Debug,
    BlockNumber: Clone + PartialEq + Debug + PartialOrd,
    MetadataSize: Get<u32>,
{
    pub account_id: Option<AccountId>,

    pub status: u32,

    pub block_number: Option<BlockNumber>,

    pub remarks: Option<BoundedVec<u8, MetadataSize>>,
}


#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn get_tracer)]
pub(super) type Tracer<T: Config> = StorageMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    BoundedVec<u8, T::MAX_T_SIZE>,
    BoundedVec<
        DataLog<T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber, T::MetadataSize>,
        T::MetadataSize,
    >,
>;

Im trying to push a value for a  vec if exists

let block_number = <frame_system::Module<T>>::block_number();
let mut dd_log = DataLog {
    account_id,
    block_number: Some(block_number),
    status,
    remarks,
};

if Tracer::<T>::contains_key(&key) {
    Tracer::<T>::mutate(key.clone(), |vc| match vc {
        | None => return Err(Error::<T>::DIDDoesNotExist),
        | Some(vc) => {
            vc.push(dd_log.clone());
            Ok(())
        },
    })?;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
466 |                     vc.push(dd_log);
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
    |
    = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `frame_support::BoundedVec<types::DataLog<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber, <T as pallet::Config>::MetadataSize>, <T as pallet::Config>::MetadataSize>`
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind `BoundedVec` is to have a vector that is ensuring that the maximum size is not exceeded. Basically it is just a wrapper around `Vec`, but most of the methods are prefixed with `try_`. The reason for the naming is that these methods are checking that the maximum size isn't exceeded and if that would happen, an error is returned.

To solve your issue, you need to call:

```
vc.try_push(dd_log.clone());
```

But as `try_push` is returning a `Result`, you still need to handle the result as this would mean that pushing to the vector was rejected because there are too many items in it.

You can find [here](https://docs.rs/bounded-collections/latest/bounded_collections/bounded_vec/struct.BoundedVec.html) all methods supported by `BoundedVec`.